# Unable to scrape this movie website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrap a movie website here: http://www.21cineplex.com/nowplaying

I have uploaded the screenshot with the HTML body as the image in this questions.[link to screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OncE1.png) I am having difficulty trying to grab the movie title and the description which is part of the `<P>` tag. For some strange reason, the description is not part of requests object. Also when I tried to use soup to find the ul and class name it cannot be found. Anyone know why? I am using python 3. This is my code so far:

```
    r = requests.get('http://www.21cineplex.com/nowplaying')
    r.text (no description here)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    soup.find('ul', class_='w462') # why is this empty?
```

Comment: maybe servers send you different page if it recognizes that you are not real web browser - try to set `user-agent` header in request.

Answer (score 2):

This server is checking `Referer` header. If there is no `Referer` it sends main page. But it doesn't check text in this header so it can be even empty string.

```
import requests
import bs4

headers = {
    #'Referer': any url (or even random text, or empty string)

    #'Referer': 'http://google.com',
    #'Referer': 'http://www.21cineplex.com',
    #'Referer': 'hello world!',
    'Referer': '',
}

s = requests.get('http://www.21cineplex.com/nowplaying', headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s.text)

for x in soup.find_all('ul', class_='w462'):
    print(x.text)

for x in soup.select('ul.w462'):
    print(x.text)

for x in soup.select('ul.w462'):
    print(x.select('a')[0].text)
    print(x.select('p')[0].text)
```