# Unable to scrape a Website using beautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried to scrape a page using beautiful soup (bs4) , but i am facing a problem while scraping data, I had even mentioned headers as pointed out in this answer [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949917/unable-to-scrape-this-movie-website-using-beautifulsoup)
This is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers = {
'Referer': 'hello',
 }
 r=requests.get
 ('https://www.doamin.com/bangalore/restaurants',headers=headers)
 print(r.status_code)
```

this is the error that i am getting

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

and this

```
 raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
 http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without 
 response
```

I even tried using the useragents

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.example.com/bangalore/restaurants'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

But still getting the same error!

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Seems like server is aborting your request. You may need to put some extra headers like `User-Agent` , etc. Also please dont add domain name which you are trying

Answer (score 1):

I guess the server is checking more thoroughly the user agent string by checking a list of valid Chrome version (if you specify a Chrome browser in user agent). The version you specified (41.0.2228) is not listed among [Chrome version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history). Use for instance 41.0.2272 :

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.example.com/bangalore/restaurants'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.0 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that Zomato (and many other data collecting websites) have implemented measures to block data scrapers or data miners. Just use their API instead: https://developers.zomato.com/api

Comment: Isn't there anyway i can do it by scraping instead?

Comment: As what @itzmeontv said, you need the right `User-Agent` and other `headers` information to even navigate around any page, to mimic the script that its a real human being. You can find the info of your own by diving into ChromeDevTools or FirefoxDevTools after loading the above page.

Comment: I tried using both headers and user-agent but still getting the same error